# vector<Mat> ::size() working misteriously

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of Mat types, with size 1 x 720 x 3 , i.e. one row, 720 columns and 3 channels . I checked the size as following

```
vector<Mat> image_rows_avg;
cout<<image_rows_avg[0].size;
```

It gives some values like 0x918840. probabely this `.size()` is giving some address. So I tried to do

`cout<<image_rows_avg[0].size[0];` which gives ans: `1`

`cout<<image_rows_avg[0].size[1];` gives ans: `720` which is correct and again 
`cout<<image_rows_avg[0].size[2];` gives ans: `159187328` again junk.

I am not able to understand what is this happening. I thought `.size()` should directly give size of vector.

Comment: `image_rows_avg.size()` will give you size of the vector and `image_rows_avg[X].size()` will give you the respective `size()` of the `X` element in the vector.

Comment: `image_rows_avg` is empty so you are accessing out of bounds.

Comment: It is not empty , it has the correct values in it.Just that I didnt post the middle part of the code, before the cout<< size line over here.

Comment: Moreover please see that I have mentioned that size(0) gives 1 which is no. of rows and size(1) gives number of columns which is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Accessing an element outside its range in a `std::vector<T>` results in undefined behavior. Your code creates an empty `std::vector<Mat>` and accesses a non-existing element.

Comment: +1, but I am waiting for "oh but this is not my real code..."

Comment: Sounds like the "I*m just asking for a friend..." of Stackoverflow :D

Comment: @above Sorry, but you were too soon to comment this way.